# Can you set custom height to a custom component in vue3?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

If you have a custom component with a div in it can you set the custom height outside of the component file?
For example:
If I have a "BaseCard" component in my App.vue file can I set the height there? If not, is there any way to have multiple "BaseCard" components, all with different heights?

Comment: the props like classes and styles you place on a component get put in the component on the first element, so if you want different heights you can just put the different classes/styles on the component when called

Answer (score 0):

You could add a prop to the component and then a computed property which saves the height in a css variable.

So where you import the component:

```
  <BaseCard :height="80vh"/>
```

And in the BaseCard.vue component:

```
<template>
    <div id="base-card" :style="cssVars"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['height'],
    computed: {
      cssVars () {
        return{
          '--card-height': this.height,
        }
    }
}
<script>

<style scoped>
#base-card{
    height: var(--card-height);
}
</style>
```